# ¿Cómo realizar comentarios multi-línea en R?

Tags: r

Hasta ahora sólo he podido comentar de la siguiente manera:

```
 # Mi Comentario 1

 # Mi Comentario 2

 # Mi Comentario 3
```

Pero quisiera saber algo equivalente a `/**/`:

```
/*
Comentario 1
Comentario 2
Comentario 3
*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lamentablemente R **no maneja comentarios multilínea**, hay un truco, que no se si es muy bueno que digamos y que pasa por escribir una cadena común multilínea, que R evaluará como tal:

```
" Esta es una prueba
  de un string multilínea que hace las veces
  de un comentario
"
```

En este caso, la cadena así escrita es relativamente inocua: se verá en la salida por consola y habrá una penalización mínima por la evaluación de la misma.

Answer (score 2):

Usando [R Studio](https://rstudio.com/) (o Eclipse) se pueden crear bloques de comentario: 
Se selecciona el texto y se usa la secuencia

**Windows:**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

o

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

**Mac:**

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

o

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Manualmente simplemente definir los bloques usando `"` como contenedor, ejemplo:

```
"#R version 3.3.2 
print("Hello, world!")
[ + ] Show input       
We've lost 2 months of data due to series of mistakes. Sorry about that.
"
```

Answer (score 1):

Una vez seleccionado el texto <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hago yo es escribir todo como si fuera un bloc de notas, y luego pongo todos los "#" de golpe. Ha un atajo de teclado Ctrl+Alt+ flecha arriba o abajo que extiende el cursos de texto varias lineas para poder introducir en varias lineas a la vez el mismo caracter, en este caso, "#".

Answer (score 0):

Sí hay forma de hacer comentario multilínea, usando

```
<!-- ejemplo
     comentario
     multilinea -->
```

espero les funcione.