# Cómo comentar un chunk entero

Tags: r

Es posible comentar el código de un chunck entero de alguna forma más sencilla que la de tener que ponerle la almohadilla en cada una de sus lineas?

Un saludo

Comment: Esta pregunta ya fue respondida aquí [¿Cómo realizar comentarios multi-línea en R?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74586/c%c3%b3mo-realizar-comentarios-multi-l%c3%adnea-en-r) te sugiero que antes de publicar chequees si ya hay una respuesta por parte de la comunidad a tu inquietud para evitar duplicados y centralizar las referencias para futuras consultas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo realizar comentarios multi-línea en R?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74586/c%c3%b3mo-realizar-comentarios-multi-l%c3%adnea-en-r)

Comment: Si lo que te interesa es que ese chunck no se evalúe cuando estás haciendo el render en el encabezado puedes poner `eval = FALSE`. Por defecto ese argumento está implícito como `eval=TRUE`.